# Could not get desired output while making custom ADT for asset publisher in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I am trying to make ADT for asset publisher such that it only show the title of the assets and when I click on a title it should show the description of that asset..but I could only get the titles displayed and desired output is not displayed when I click them. The code for ADT is as follows which I tried:-

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as curEntry>
    <#assign assetURL = assetPublisherHelper.getAssetViewURL(renderRequest, renderResponse,curEntry) />
    <a href="${assetURL}">${curEntry.getTitle(locale)}</a><br/>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Comment: what *is* displayed when you click them? E.g. what does `${assetURL}` evaluate to?

Comment: its value is http://localhost:8080/web/guest/volunteer/-/asset_publisher/4d1CJdgNOhHy/content/hi-1?_101_INSTANCE_4d1CJdgNOhHy_redirect=%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fvolunteer